# Pattern Matching Enhancement: Switch Pattern

Tags: .net-core-3.0, c#-8.0, switch-expression

Just had a look at the "new" [C# 8.0 Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#more-patterns-in-more-places)

So I tried to rewrite the following code

```
    private static void RunExample(ExampleCode exampleCode)
    {
        switch(exampleCode)
        {
            case ExampleCode.DefaultInterfaceMethod:
                RunDefaultInterfaceMethodExample();
                break;
            case ExampleCode.PatternMatchingEnhancements:
                RunPatternMatchingEnhancementsExample();
                break;
        }      
    }
```

to this:

```
    private static void RunExample(ExampleCode exampleCode)
    {
        exampleCode switch
        {
            ExampleCode.DefaultInterfaceMethod => RunDefaultInterfaceMethodExample(),
            ExampleCode.PatternMatchingEnhancements => RunPatternMatchingEnhancementsExample()
        };           
    }
```

However, I am getting the following compile error:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object
>   expressions can be used as a statement.

[image: Compile Error]

How can I rewrite this in the new syntax?

Comment: What options are you compiling with? What does that prominent "Show potential fixes" suggest?

Comment: @underscore_d .NET Core 3.0. Potential fixes shows literally 'Nothing' ;-)

Comment: As the error is pointing you are not allowed to fire and forget, which means that the new pattern matching switch is expecting to return something (this is common for expression, it happens so that c# does not treat void as actual result), if your cases where returning results and then assign the result to variable you will be OK.

Comment: @vasiloreshenski Then how would you resolve it beautifully?

Comment: @Fabian                                                                                                           Refer this link                        
https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/06/25/switch-expressions-in-c-8/

Comment: @IshwarGagare Thanks for your reply, but this does not solve the issue at hand.

Comment: @FabianBigler this is a completely new switch *expression*. Like all expressions, it *has* to produce a value.  It's not alternative syntax for the old switch *statement*

Comment: @FabianBigler in any case, the original code isn't using pattern matching, it looks like switching on enum values. You can't use exhaustive pattern matching with enum values (they are just numbers after all), so you won't get any benefit from using a switch expression

Answer (score 3):

As pointed in the comments the new switch based pattern matching is expecting result to be returned.

In **F#** because everything is an expression, the `void` type is actually a valid return type for an expression and this would have worked.

In case like yours i think it is best to use the old code, but if you really want to use the new syntax you can do something like this:

```
Action methodToExecute = exampleCode switch
{
  ExampleCode.DefaultInterfaceMethod => RunDefaultInterfaceMethodExample,
  ExampleCode.PatternMatchingEnhancements => RunPatternMatchingEnhancementsExample,
  _ => throw new NotImplementedException()
};     
methodToExecute();
```

**(this will work only if the methods you are executing for each case have the same definitions)**

It is good practice to use exhaustive pattern, this is why i am using the last case with the underscore.
In C# enum values are compiled to integers and even if your switch handles all enum labels the compiler still does not know you have handled all cases and when you add new label to the enum you won't have proper warrning that you are have unhandled case.

Whenever you are using enums it is best to use default case where all unhandled cases will fall in.

Comment: So it is as expected. Then I will definetely stick to the old code. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @FabianBigler Yeah best thing to do :)